# Attempting to hover over an element using javascript in selenium with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I have working in to create a test that causes a hidden element to appear on a page when an another element is hovered over by the mouse pointer, but I have not had much luck.  The element is not normally visible on the page, and can only be found or grabbed while it is visible.  I have tried the following to get it to appear, but it wants an Event as an element and I'm not too familiar with javascript.

`((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(mouseover);", elementToHoverOver);`

It tells me that mouseover is not defined, but I thought it was an event.  What is an event in javascript then, and can I do all this in one line of code using what I have above?

I have also tried

```
Actions act = new Actions(Driver);
act.MoveToElement(element).Build().Perform();
```

Followed by a wait, but this does not make the element appear, and clicking the element will not make the pop-up show either.

Comment: Please post a link to the page or the relevant HTML. My guess is that your attempted hover isn't hovering the right element. You should be able to do this with `Actions` (and it should be a lot easier than trying to do it with JSE).

Comment: Can't post a link because the page is not public, sorry.  I know I am hovering the correct object, I have checked the hover location to confirm it.  There is a weird interaction where if I run the test and loop the perform action, if I move my physical mouse and the visual pointer while the test is in this loop, the popup appears.  If I don't move the mouse, it doesn't appear.  I don't even need the on-screen cursor to be over the element while the test is in the loop, just to move it and have the cursor on-screen move, and the popup shows.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for dispatchEvent ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) for instance), you'll see that it's waiting for an Event object, so unless you defined an Event somewhere like this:

`var mouseover = <Event definition here>`

Then mouseover is undefined. If you have the element in javascript, you can simply call `elementToHoverOver.onmouseover()` to trigger the hover event, provided that elementToHoverOver exists in the javascript code.

To clarify, this code is javascript code, so assuming that somewhere in your javascript you have something like this:

`var myElement = document.getElementById("myelementid");`

You can then use the Javascript executor to call the onmouseover event.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("myElement.onmouseover()");
```

You can also directly call `document.getElementById` in ExecuteScript if you don't have an appropriate variable on the javascript side.  (Or replace document.getElementById with another way to identify the element if it doesn't have an id).

`((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementById("myelementid").onmouseover()");`

Comment: I guess I'm confused then, as on the page you link mouseover is listed as an event, so I thought providing it to dispatchEvent would work.  Is there some syntax there that I am missing?

Comment: mouseover is the name of an event, it's not an actual event object (at least not in your code, so it can't be accessed as simply as typing mouseover). To create an event object, you'd have to actually call a constructor, something like `var event = new Event("myeventname"), and then call dispatchEvent(event).  You could probably create the mouseover event through the MouseEvent class, but why not use the onmouseover() function?

Comment: I have tried using onmouseover(), but visual studio gives me an error  stating that it isn't a function.  The main problem is that I am writing everything in C#, but nothing I have found in C# can make the popup appear, so I am trying to use the javascript behind the element to force the popup to appear.

Comment: Right, because that's not c# code, that's javascript code. I've updated with a more detailed example.

Comment: After reading over some more information, I'm unsure if I should be trying to trigger onmouseover() or popover().  Is popover() a generic method I can trigger through jquery?

Comment: I would get in the habit of searching documentation for simple stuff like this. A quick look at https://api.jquery.com/?s=popover shows that popover isn't a jQuery concept.  Maybe you're thinking of the bootstrap popover plugin?

Comment: yeah, I'm gonna have to look at bootstrap.  Sorry, just a bit frustrated.  I know that I have put the cursor on the correct spot, I know that I have the right element and spot on the page, but I can't get the popup window to show.  It's either that or attempt to take hold of and move the actual on-screen cursor, not  use a simulated one.  As stated above, when running the test and looping through the actions that put the pseudo pointer onto the correct element, if I move the real mouse while that loop is running, it causes the popup to appear, but I can't figure out the exact reason why.

Comment: Have you tried it with my changes? Does the test work, but the popover doesn't appear? As far as I know, the bootstrap popover appears on a click, not just a hover (though you may have logic that modifies that behaviour).

Comment: I did, the test runs, but the popup is not triggered and does not appear.  This popup was designed to only appear when hovered over, it does not appear on a click.  I finally got it to show up.  I ran a loop 3 times where it uses an IMouse interface to move to the element, then uses the SetCursorPos() method from dll import to move to it, and after looping the 3rd time the popup appears.  I am unsure of why this works, but it seems to do so.  I have not yet tried bootstrap, but I may still look into it.  I am also looking to see if using winforms might be better.

Comment: This actually worked for us when we supplied `onmouseover` without the parentheses. In Java:
`((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].onmouseover;", element);`